# Function returns only one iteration, instead of multiple. What is wrong?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, matrix, return

First of all I'm a beginner and having an issue about functions and returning values. After that, I need to do some matrix operations to take minimum value of the right column. However, since I cannot return these values (I could not figure out why) I'm not able to do any operations on it. The problem here is, every time I try to use `return`, It gives me only the first or the last row of the matrix. If you can help, I really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Yunus Özer\Downloads/MA.csv")
df.head()
x = df["x"]
def minreg():
    for k in range(2,16):
        x_pred = np.full(x.shape, np.nan)
        for t in range(k,x.size):
            x_pred[t] = np.mean(x[(t-k):t])
        mape_value=((np.mean(np.abs(x-x_pred)/np.abs(x))*100))
        m=np.array([k,mape_value])
        return m
print(minreg())
```

Comment: `m` is only a particular row that your code is printing. So if you're doing `return m` before or after the loop it's going to be the first/last row. Also note please do not use screenshots for code, instead copy and paste it as a code block on the site.

Comment: Ok, thanks but what should I return then?

Comment: Considering that you making this on the loop. You can create an empty array and append to that array instead of printing. Then return that created array after your loop.

Comment: Hi. You should post your code in the question instead of an image. Check [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557) for more info.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Sorry about that, new here. Just could not figure out how to copy paste in the appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

`return m` command basicly terminates the function and returns `m`. As a result, the function terminates after executing the first loop. So firstly you need to call return after your loop ends. Secondly you need to put each m value generated for the loop to an array to store them and return that array.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Yunus Özer\Downloads/MA.csv")
df.head()
x = df["x"]
def minreg():
    m_arr = []
    for k in range(2,16):
        x_pred = np.full(x.shape, np.nan)
        for t in range(k,x.size):
            x_pred[t] = np.mean(x[(t-k):t])
        mape_value=((np.mean(np.abs(x-x_pred)/np.abs(x))*100))
        m_arr.append(np.array([k,mape_value]))
    return m_arr
print(minreg())
```

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a lot.. Really appreciate.

Comment: @YunusÖzer You can accept my answer if your problem is solved. Glad I helped.